# Panel background color as item in JComboBox

Tags: background, combobox, panel

I have one panel and one combobox. Basically what I want to do is to make the color of the panel as one of the items of the combobox. Picture below describe this. In the upper part is the expected result and below is what is finaly displayed.

[image]

Source Code

Click a button, open a dialog and register the Panel1 color in an array

```
private void bTestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    showingColors[0] = Panel1.getBackground();
    testDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

The combobox creation. Notice that in the colors array the last 3 colors are just for testing purposes.

```
Color[] colors={showingColors[0],Color.red,Color.blue,Color.green};
CBackground = new javax.swing.JComboBox(colors);
CBackground.setMaximumRowCount(6);
CBackground.setRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

MyCellRenderer class

```
class MyCellRenderer extends JButton implements ListCellRenderer {  
 public MyCellRenderer() {  
     setOpaque(true); 

 }
 boolean b=false;

 @Override
public void setBackground(Color bg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(!b)
     {
         return;
     }

    super.setBackground(bg);
}

 @Override
 public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)  
 {  
     b=true;
     setText(" ");           
     setBackground((Color)value);        
     b=false;
     return this;  
 }  

} //End of class MySellRenderer
```

Comment: There's no need to change the title. The proper way to show an answer is solved is to either upvote it, or accept an answer. As it's your own question, you can't accept an answer for a few days, but come back here then to do so.

Comment: I apologize for this!

Comment: No problem, we were all new once;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. I made a function that creates a new DefaultComboBoxModel with the array that has my color stored and I call this function in the ActionListener of the button that opens the Dialog.

```
private void fillSelectCombos(JComboBox box1) {
  DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel( showingColors );
  box1.setModel( model );
  box1.setRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
}
```

And the button listener

```
private void bTestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    setColorsArray();
    fillSelectCombos(CBackground);
    testDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```